# How to keep extra fields added by js on refresh

Tags: javascript

```
  var container = document.createElement("lastExp");
  container.innerHTML = 'html code new form field';
  document.getElementById("lastExp").appendChild(container);
```

It's simple i click button extra form field is added.
Question: When i refresh page how to not lose this extra fields on my form.

Comment: Cookies or localStorage - front-end.

Comment: Ok, I could have exaggerated a bit. Under the hood, you have to append that element every time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not the place to write code, but this will sits here in case someone besides OP need.

It's a minimal example--getting started--with `localStorage`. As I mentioned, under the hood, you have to append that element every time the page is loaded.

The snippet won't work here, unfortunately because the iframe is sandbox'd. Head over to [my hub](https://hub.adama.io/local-storage/) to experiment it.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    toggle    = document.getElementById('toggle');
    element   = null;

// initial check
init();

// add click event and listen for clicks
toggle.onclick = function() {
  // both cases will update localStoage _inputIsThere
  // if element is null -- doesn't exists, then add it
  if (element == null) {
    add();
  } else {
    // remove the element 
    remove();
  }
}

// check if key exists in localStorage; this is where all the "magic" happens.
function init() {
  var exists = localStorage.getItem('_inputIsThere');
  if (exists && exists == 'true') {
    add();
  }
}


function remove() {
  element.remove();
  element = null;
  // update key in localStorage to false
  localStorage.setItem('_inputIsThere', false);
}

// adds the input and updates 
function add() {

  var e = document.createElement('input');
  e.type = 'text';
  element = e;
  container.appendChild(e);
  // update key in localStorage to true
  localStorage.setItem('_inputIsThere', true);

}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Add/Remove</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```